# How to pass block to sub method?

Tags: ruby

Say I have the following code:

```
def a(n, m, &block)
  yield if block_given?
end

def a
  # My question is here. When a is called, block might be or might not be
  # given. Below line is obvious wrong. How to call b and properly pass 
  # block to b?
  b(1, 2, &block)
end

a  # call a without block

a { # call a with a block
    puts "in block"
}
```

Comment: Not at all clear what you're asking. Was your first function supposed to be called `b`? The line you indicate is *not* obviously wrong, it's correct.

Comment: @meagar Well the line it likely wrong because—barring a method of that name—`block` is undefined there.

Comment: Please don't write the question as a comment to code. Write it as text.

Comment: Redefining `a` makes the first definition of `a` meaningless. You haven't shown what `b` is. It is not clear what you are doing.

Answer (score 10):

Write `a()` to accept a block. It is implied to be optional, and as Andrew Marshall noted, will be passed along as `&nil` if not given.

```
def b(n, m, &block)
  yield if block_given?
  puts "no block" if !block_given?
end

def a( &block )
  b(1, 2, &block)
end

a  # call a without block

a { # call a with a block
    puts "in block"
}
```

Output:

```
no block
in block
```

Comment: Actually, you don’t need the conditional in `a`. If no block is given then `block` is `nil` and since `f(&nil)` is like passing no block you can just pass it along in either case and it will work as expected. (Ex: `def f &block; [block, block_given?]; end; f(&nil) #=> [nil, false]`.)

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Excellent point, thank you. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: ```puts "no block" unless block_given?``` will be more Ruby-ish. :)